# Change font after a symbol, html / css only

Tags: html, css, squarespace

I'm currently developing a site on `Squarespace` and I need to change the font after a certain symbol in the phrase. I don't have Full Access to the script.

So, I can only edit from the code injection page on `Squarespace`. Can someone please help?

[image: Image Example]

After the "-" I need the font to change to paragraph styling so there is some hierarchy in the heading.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a `Squarespace` developer but after googling i think you can edit `html`, `css` there.

So, Why don't you do this,

```css
p {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif; /***/
}

p span {
  font-family: 'Yellowtail', cursive;; /***/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Orbitron&family=Yellowtail&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


<p>
<span>Evolution of a model</span> - BEAU young Charts The Process of developing a new model from the shaping bay to produce blah blah lbah....
<p>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three options for achieving that in Squarespace:

1. Use JavaScript to wrap the target text in its own `span` element which you can then apply inline styles or classes to.
2. Use a code or markdown block and wrap the target text within a `span`. As with #1, you can then apply inline styles to the span or apply classes and style it via CSS.
3. Highlight the text and mark it as either bold or italic, or both. Then use that distinction to target it within your CSS using the section or block ID in combination with `strong` and/or `em`.

See a related question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59332357/how-do-i-add-css-class-names-to-text-blocks-in-squarespace?noredirect=1&lq=1).